# Python script won't properly separate objects in json file

Tags: python, json, append

I'm trying to code a Pokédex in Python that adds data of the Pokémon you meet for my current assignment in school.
I have two json files, one of which contains all the info for the G1 starter Pokémon while the other starts as an empty file.
The Python file pulls data from the former and appends to the latter.
Unfortunately I can't find how to make it so that the json file that gets appended to has its objects separated properly.

This is what the Python code looks like:

```
# importing modules
import json
from os import path

# check if output file exists and load it
filename = 'full_pokedex.json'

if path.isfile(filename) is False:
    raise Exception("File not found")

with open("full_pokedex.json", "r") as read_file:
  input_file_dict = json.load(read_file)

# input field (for testing purposes)
pkmn = input("Enter the name of a G1 starter Pokémon: ")

# write Bulbasaur in json file    
if pkmn == "Bulbasaur":
    inc_id_list = [1]

    output_dict = dict()

    for id in input_file_dict.keys():
        if int(id) in inc_id_list:
            output_dict[id] = input_file_dict.get(id)
        
    with open('pokedex.json', 'a') as output_json_file:
        json.dump(output_dict, output_json_file, indent = 1, separators=(',',": "), ensure_ascii=False)
    
    print("Data added to Pokédex")

# write Charmender in json file
if pkmn == "Charmander":
    inc_id_list = [4]

    output_dict = dict()

    for id in input_file_dict.keys():
        if int(id) in inc_id_list:
            output_dict[id] = input_file_dict.get(id)
        
    with open('pokedex.json', 'a') as output_json_file:
        json.dump(output_dict, output_json_file, indent = 1, separators=(',',": "), ensure_ascii=False)
    
    print("Data added to Pokédex")

# write Squirtle in json file        
if pkmn == "Squirtle":
    inc_id_list = [7]

    output_dict = dict()

    for id in input_file_dict.keys():
        if int(id) in inc_id_list:
            output_dict[id] = input_file_dict.get(id)
        
    with open('pokedex.json', 'a') as output_json_file:
        json.dump(output_dict, output_json_file, indent = 1, separators=(',',": "), ensure_ascii=False)
    
    print("Data added to Pokédex")
```

The full Pokédex json file looks like this, and represents what the formatting should look like:

```
{
"1": {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Bulbasaur",
  "type": "Plant",
  "HP": 45,
  "Attack": 49,
  "Defense": 49,
  "Sp. Attack": 65,
  "Sp. Defense": 65,
  "Speed": 45
},
"4": {
  "id": 4,
  "name": "Charmander",
  "type": "Fire",
  "HP": 39,
  "Attack": 52,
  "Defense": 43,
  "Sp. Attack": 60,
  "Sp. Defense": 50,
  "Speed": 65
},
"7": {
  "id": 7,
  "name": "Squirtle",
  "type": "Water",
  "HP": 44,
  "Attack": 48,
  "Defense": 65,
  "Sp. Attack": 50,
  "Sp. Defense": 64,
  "Speed": 43
 }
}
```

Upon executing the code 3 times with a different Pokémon picked each time, this is what the Pokédex json file looks like:

```
{
 "1": {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Bulbasaur",
  "type": "Plant",
  "HP": 45,
  "Attack": 49,
  "Defense": 49,
  "Sp. Attack": 65,
  "Sp. Defense": 65,
  "Speed": 45
 }
}{
 "4": {
  "id": 4,
  "name": "Charmander",
  "type": "Fire",
  "HP": 39,
  "Attack": 52,
  "Defense": 43,
  "Sp. Attack": 60,
  "Sp. Defense": 50,
  "Speed": 65
 }
}{
 "7": {
  "id": 7,
  "name": "Squirtle",
  "type": "Water",
  "HP": 44,
  "Attack": 48,
  "Defense": 65,
  "Sp. Attack": 50,
  "Sp. Defense": 64,
  "Speed": 43
 }
}
```

As you can see, objects aren't properly separated.
It should look like this: `{{object1},{object2}}`
instead of this: `{{object1}}{{object2}}`

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I tried formatting the json file which my Python script pulls from by making an array with brackets:

```
[
"1", {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Bulbasaur",
  "type": "Plant",
  "HP": 45,
  "Attack": 49,
  "Defense": 49,
  "Sp. Attack": 65,
  "Sp. Defense": 65,
  "Speed": 45
},
"4", {
  "id": 4,
  "name": "Charmander",
  "type": "Fire",
  "HP": 39,
  "Attack": 52,
  "Defense": 43,
  "Sp. Attack": 60,
  "Sp. Defense": 50,
  "Speed": 65
},
"7", {
  "id": 7,
  "name": "Squirtle",
  "type": "Water",
  "HP": 44,
  "Attack": 48,
  "Defense": 65,
  "Sp. Attack": 50,
  "Sp. Defense": 64,
  "Speed": 43
 }
]
```

but it returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\crost\Documents\Projets\Pokemon\src\pokedex\pokedex.py", line 38, in <module>
    for id in input_file_dict.keys():
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Comment: if json is not mandatory, i'd go for csv instead. you can't just append your json file and expect it to behave like a big dict

Comment: Unfortunately it is mandatory. Been struggling with this thing for a while now. I appreciate the suggestion though.

Comment: you might like `pickle.dump` rather than `json.dump`

Comment: json is mandatory, I can't use pickle

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is coming from the fact that you are appending each object separately to the JSON file, hence the extra '{}'. I would try adding all your data to the object by updating it before dumping it into the final file once at the end.
Start by creating an existing_data dictionary that you can update with each pokemon later. It may end up looking something like this:

```
try:
with open("pokedex.json", "r") as existing_file:
    existing_data = json.load(existing_file)
except FileNotFoundError:
    existing_data = {}


pkmn = input("Enter the name of a G1 starter Pokémon: ")

pokemon_data = {
    "Bulbasaur": 1,
    "Charmander": 4,
    "Squirtle": 7
}
if pkmn in pokemon_data:
    inc_id = pokemon_data[pkmn]

    output_dict = {inc_id: input_file_dict.get(str(inc_id))}

    existing_data.update(output_dict)


    with open('pokedex.json', 'w') as output_json_file:
        json.dump(existing_data, output_json_file, indent=1, separators= 
        (',', ": "), ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried implementing the code you wrote [like this](https://pastebin.com/vb3K1wgv) but it returns an error.